# Issue showing an Image using the imageview from JavaFx

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, imageview, javafx-8

I got a problem showing an image using the imageview from javafx ...

First is I load the stored image(Blob) from mySql then pass it to my Model class as ByteArrayInputStream.

At First when you click the 'Info' Button at the first time it will Open the 'INFO' class and showing you the image, but when you close it and reOpen it  then the image suddenly disappear or not showing anything.

**Opening it at First Time**

[image]

you can see the image, but ...

**if you reopen the class again**

[image]

It will show you nothing or the image doesn't load

Here's the codes:

```
public void setPerson(Person person){

    this.person = person;
    ByteArrayInputStream in = person.getImage();
    if(in != null){
        iv_image.setImage(new Image(person.getImage()));    
    }else{
        iv_image.setImage(null);
    }

    lbl_id.setText("" + person.getId());
    lbl_date.setText(person.getDate());
    lbl_fname.setText(person.getFname());
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to reuse the same input stream? You are probably going to need to paste some code with this.

Comment: ok i added the code i use for showing the image.

Comment: i solve it now.. this what i did. 
in.mark(0);
   iv_image.setImage(new Image(person.getGuardImage())); 
   in.reset();